# Wavelet, scaling, detail, and smooth/approximation coefficients

Tags: wavelet, discrete-wavelet-transform

I was reading through the documentation for the R `wavelets` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavelets/wavelets.pdf) and doing a little experimentation and noticed that the `modwt` and `mra` functions have similar outputs, yet the coefficients are called different things.  The `modwt` function produces wavelet and scaling coefficients (`W` and `V`), whereas the `mra` function produces detail and smooth coefficients (`D` and `S`).

```
library("wavelets")

mod = modwt(data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4)), filter="haar", n.levels=3)
wtrma = mra(data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4)), filter="haar", n.levels=3, method="modwt")
```

What I'm trying to figure out what the differences are between these two sets of coefficients and how they work together (assuming they do), especially since the `mra` function can take a method of `"modwt"`.

I did see this [explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61741/meaning-of-wavelet-and-scaling-coefficients) of scaling versus wavelet coefficients, however, I'm not sure if the example aligns with MODWT.  I'm specifically trying to learn about multiresolution analysis as I understand it can fit with ensemble machine learning regression strategies and I saw some references to it specifically being used with MODWT, but I seem to be lacking the basics in terms of wavelet transforms.  I think part of the confusion is that multiresolution analysis is a term used for wavelet transforms, however `modwt` is described in the R package as a type of wavelet transform and it's distinct from the `mra` function.

If anyone can suggest an online course, that would also be helpful.